# Date Format in JavaScript using toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, date

I am having some problem when trying to format date in JavaScript. Here is the code:

```
var date = new Date(tenderClosingDate);
                        var d = new Date(date.toLocaleDateString());
                        tenderClosingDate = ((d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCDate() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCFullYear()));
```

By using this code, 11/29/2012 should be working but somehow it returns me NaN. Is there any way to format it to become dd/mm/yyyy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused about why you're creating that intermediate `d` variable for a Date object, when its value should be identical to `date`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What turns out as NaN? Why this code would not do what you want: tenderClosingDate = ((d.getUTCDate() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + (d.getUTCFullYear()));?

Comment: Use console.log(date) right after creating it.
If the initial value of `tenderClosingDate` cannot be parsed correctly, it'll all go wrong from the get-go.

Comment: My data was in this format: 2003/09/22 00:00:00 UTC. let's say 11/29/2003, it turns out showing error message which I replace them with NaN. If it was 6/7/2003 it turns out well. I guess is because somehow the browser or something was reading the date format in dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a date... and you're trying to create a new date from that date in a way that the browser won't ever recognise...

Just use `date.getUTCMonth()` etc.

Also note, while the month is 0-based (for use in an array like `['Jan','Feb',...]`), the date is not and you'll end up looking silly with things like January 32nd.

Comment: Because my date was retrieved from some data and I try to parse them

Answer (score 0):

This code works only if the original value of `tenderClosingDate` contains either the elapsed milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch), or a string value representing a date. If the original value of `tenderClosingDate` is an empty string, a date string which cannot be parsed by `Date.parse`, or `undefined`, then the result will contain `NaN`s.